# Can I change OpenXava login password (without XavaPro)?

Tags: java, security, openxava

When I run my OpenXava application the only way to sign in is using 'admin' as user and 'admin' as password:

[image: OpenXava Welcome Page]

How can I define a different password for admin user? Using plain OpenXava, not XavaPro.

Answer (score 1):

In the folder 'properties' inside your project you can find a file called naviox-users.properties, with this content:

```
# In plain OpenXava the users are added here in the form user=password
# If you want full management of users, roles and modules stored in database, 
#   get XavaPro from here: http://www.openxava.org/xavapro

admin=admin
```

Edit it, and change admin=admin by admin=yourownpassword. You have to restart your application in order it has effect.

To learn more about security and user management with OpenXava look at:
https://openxava.org/OpenXavaDoc/docs/security_en.html